# How to show only one div with same class then others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a garage system and when my user clicks on a selected item, I wish to show the car picture for it. However the divs that contain the images all have the same class name, so all cars are showing up.

I'm trying to show only the `class="imagem"` from the selected item (active) not all.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  let $el = $(this);
  let isActive = $el.hasClass('active');

  $('.item').removeClass('active');
  $('.imagem').fadeOut(500);

  if (!isActive) {
    $el.addClass('active');
    $('.imagem').fadeIn(500);
  }

});
```

```css
.imagem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h1>GARAGE</h1>
</div>
<div id="subtitle">
  <span class="sub1">MODEL: </span>
  <span class="sub2">DOCUMENTS:</span>
  <span class="sub3">PRICE:</span>
  </br>
</div>
<div class="item" data-item-name="bugatti">
  <div id="itemname">Bugatti</div>
  <div id="itemqtd">Indeed</div>
  <div id="itempeso">$ 320.100</div>
  <div class="imagem">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 132px;" src="http://177.54.152.85/imgallstar/bugatti.png" />
    <div class="status">
      <span class="stat1">Motor: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Chassis: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Fuel: </span><span class="stat2">10%</span></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-item-name="another">
  <div id="itemname">Another Car</div>
  <div id="itemqtd">Indeed</div>
  <div id="itempeso">$ 20.000</div>
  <div class="imagem">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 132px;" src="http://177.54.152.85/imgallstar/another.png" />
    <div class="status">
      <span class="stat1">Motor: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Chassis: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Fuel: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `'.imagem'` is a child of the item.  You just need to find it in the `$el`

Comment: sorry my english/
I've already trying to use child and index, but I'm inexperient to it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a variable for the div you want to affect and then use the [jquery find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) option to just get the nested div.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  let $el = $(this);
  let isActive = $el.hasClass('active');

  $('.item').removeClass('active');
  
  //Delcare variable as jquery object and just get the closest div
  var $imageDiv = $el.find('.imagem');
  $imageDiv.fadeOut(500);

  if (!isActive) {
    $el.addClass('active');
    $imageDiv.fadeIn(500);
  }

});
```

```css
.imagem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h1>GARAGE</h1>
</div>
<div id="subtitle">
  <span class="sub1">MODEL: </span>
  <span class="sub2">DOCUMENTS:</span>
  <span class="sub3">PRICE:</span>
  </br>
</div>
<div class="item" data-item-name="bugatti">
  <div id="itemname">Bugatti</div>
  <div id="itemqtd">Indeed</div>
  <div id="itempeso">$ 320.100</div>
  <div class="imagem">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 132px;" src="http://177.54.152.85/imgallstar/bugatti.png" />
    <div class="status">
      <span class="stat1">Motor: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Chassis: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Fuel: </span><span class="stat2">10%</span></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-item-name="another">
  <div id="itemname">Another Car</div>
  <div id="itemqtd">Indeed</div>
  <div id="itempeso">$ 20.000</div>
  <div class="imagem">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 132px;" src="http://177.54.152.85/imgallstar/another.png" />
    <div class="status">
      <span class="stat1">Motor: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Chassis: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Fuel: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

$('.imagem')` will always return you all the available elements on the page.

You have to find the `.imagem` class from its parent with [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  let $el = $(this);
  let isActive = $el.hasClass('active');

  $('.item').removeClass('active');
  $el.find('.imagem').fadeOut(500);

  if (!isActive) {
    $el.addClass('active');
    $el.find('.imagem').fadeIn(500);
  }

});
```

```css
.imagem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h1>GARAGE</h1>
</div>
<div id="subtitle">
  <span class="sub1">MODEL: </span>
  <span class="sub2">DOCUMENTS:</span>
  <span class="sub3">PRICE:</span>
  </br>
</div>
<div class="item" data-item-name="bugatti">
  <div id="itemname">Bugatti</div>
  <div id="itemqtd">Indeed</div>
  <div id="itempeso">$ 320.100</div>
  <div class="imagem">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 132px;" src="http://177.54.152.85/imgallstar/bugatti.png" />
    <div class="status">
      <span class="stat1">Motor: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Chassis: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Fuel: </span><span class="stat2">10%</span></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item" data-item-name="another">
  <div id="itemname">Another Car</div>
  <div id="itemqtd">Indeed</div>
  <div id="itempeso">$ 20.000</div>
  <div class="imagem">
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 132px;" src="http://177.54.152.85/imgallstar/another.png" />
    <div class="status">
      <span class="stat1">Motor: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Chassis: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
      <span class="stat1">Fuel: </span><span class="stat2">100%</span></br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It Worked,
I had to keep the first one with
$('.imagem').fadeOut(500)
because if not, when i was clicking on another item , it was keeping showing up, but THANKSSS, you're alwesome <3 I spend more then 6 hours trying to fix it